# Make POST call with XML payload with HTTPie

Tags: xml, http, curl, payload, httpie

Is there equivalent way to make this cURL call with HTTPie?

```
curl -k -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodCall><methodName>wp.getUsersBlogs</methodName><params><param><value>user</value></param><param><value>pass</value></param></params></methodCall>' https://crmpicco.co.uk/xmlrpc.php
```

I have tried the following without any success:

```
http --pretty=all --verify=no POST https://crmpicco.co.uk/xmlrpc.php data="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodCall><methodName>wp.getUsersBlogs</methodName><params><param><value>admin</value></param><param><value>pass</value></param></params></methodCall>"
```

I prefer using HTTPie, but in this instance i've had to fallback to cURL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With HTTPie you use `stdin` to pass raw request body data, for example:

```sh
PAYLOAD='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodCall><methodName>wp.getUsersBlogs</methodName><params><param><value>admin</value></param><param><value>pass</value></param></params></methodCall>'

echo "$PAYLOAD" | http --verify=no https://crmpicco.co.uk/xmlrpc.php
```

Documentation: https://httpie.org/doc#redirected-input

Comment: Great, thanks. Doable without setting the variable too, e.g. `echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodCall><methodName>wp.getUsersBlogs</methodName><params><param><value>admin</value></param><param><value>pass</value></param></params></methodCall>' | http --verify=no https://crmpicco.co.uk/xmlrpc.php`